# Merging 4 matrices to one matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am struggling with the task to merge four matrices as presented below. Since the matrices A-D contain more than just four entries it would be too complex to do it by hand. Is there a simple or clever way to get the result in Mathematica?

```
A = {{A11,A12},
      {A21,A22}}

B = {{B11,B12},
      {B21,B22}}

C = {{C11,C12},
      {C21,C22}}

D = {{D11,D12},
      {D21,D22}}


E = {{A11,B11,A12,B12},
      {C11,D11,C12,D12},
      {A21,B21,A22,B22},
      {C21,D21,C22,D22}}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Max

Comment: Look for Join in the documentation

Comment: I have seen Join in the documentation already, but how can I use it to get the distribution I am looking for?  I don't understand this point.

Answer (score 13):

Not necessarily optimal, but it works:

```
a = {{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}};

b = {{B11, B12}, {B21, B22}};

c = {{C11, C12}, {C21, C22}};

d = {{D11, D12}, {D21, D22}};

Flatten[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{3, 1}, {4, 2}}]
```

> ```
> {{A11, B11, A12, B12},
>  {C11, D11, C12, D12},
>  {A21, B21, A22, B22},
>  {C21, D21, C22, D22}}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

```
a = {{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}};
b = {{B11, B12}, {B21, B22}};
c = {{C11, C12}, {C21, C22}};
d = {{D11, D12}, {D21, D22}};

ArrayFlatten[Transpose[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {3, 4, 1, 2}]]
(*    {{A11, B11, A12, B12},
       {C11, D11, C12, D12},
       {A21, B21, A22, B22},
       {C21, D21, C22, D22}}    *)
```

Answer (score 8):

A (probably) very slow but very explicit solution:

```
a = {{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}};
b = {{B11, B12}, {B21, B22}};
c = {{C11, C12}, {C21, C22}};
d = {{D11, D12}, {D21, D22}};

Riffle[
 MapThread[Riffle, {a, b}],
 MapThread[Riffle, {c, d}]
 ]
```

> ```
> {
>   {A11, B11, A12, B12}, 
>   {C11, D11, C12, D12}, 
>   {A21, B21, A22, B22}, 
>   {C21, D21, C22, D22}
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you all very much :)